# python: i want to merge different dictionaries by same key and add dictionary name to key

Tags: python

i want to merge dictionary and add dictionary name to key

```
key + dictionaryname : value(which is biggest)
```

i have three dictionaries like below

```
mall1_d = {'apple': 1000, 'pineapple': 2}

mall2_d = {'apple': 1100, 'pineapple': 5}

mall3_d = {'apple': 1200, 'pineapple': 3}

malldict = {'mall1':mall1_d, 'mall2':mall2_d, 'mall3':mall3_d}
```

i tried below method

```
def mergedict():
    for name,dict_ in malldict.items():
        for d in dict_:
            print({k + name: max(v) for k, v in d.items()})
mergedict()
```

**expected result**

```
{'applemall3':1200, 'pineapplemall2':5}
```

but i got error like this

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: These snippets do not work with one another. You have different variables in them. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Note that objects don't know their name, and in fact can have from 0 to arbitrary many names. If you want to use "a name", you must explicitly define it as data, e.g. ``{'apple': 1000, 'pineapple': 2, 'name': 'mall1'}``

Comment: The `AttributeError` comes from referencing `.items()`. There are 2 places where you do this. Are you doing this on `dict` instance at both places ?

Comment: `for d in dict_:` - `d` will be the keys of the *current* dictionary (which are strings) then you try `print(....d.items()})`. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `dictionary` with values as `tuples` to store the max values. The keys of the dictionary are the *fruit names*. The elements of the tuples(dictionary values) are the *mall names* and the *max values*, respectively.

```
mall1_d = {'apple': 1000, 'pineapple': 2}

mall2_d = {'apple': 1100, 'pineapple': 5}

mall3_d = {'apple': 1200, 'pineapple': 3}

malldict = {'mall1':mall1_d, 'mall2':mall2_d, 'mall3':mall3_d}

def mergeDict(d):
    maxDict = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            inDict = k1 in maxDict
            if (not inDict) or (inDict and v1 > maxDict[k1][1]):
                maxDict[k1] = (k, v1)
    result = {k + maxDict[k][0]: maxDict[k][1] for k in maxDict}
    print(result)
    
mergeDict(malldict)
```